# Error: Cannot read property 'send' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to build a signup api service, the first step is to check is the user email exist, if exist the server will send "email exist " response else the user will be saved successfully in the data base (mongoDB).

her is the code :

```
userRoutes.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.email ||  !req.body.password || !req.body.firstname || !req.body.lastname || !req.body.gender || !req.body.country || !req.body.town || !req.body.isTrainer) {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: 'set up required fields' });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            email:      req.body.email,
            password:   req.body.password,
            firstname:  req.body.firstname,
            lastname:   req.body.lastname,
            gender:     req.body.gender,
            country:    req.body.country,
            town:       req.body.town,
            isTrainer:  req.body.isTraine   
        });

        User.find({ email: req.body.email}, function(res,err, user){
            if (err) {
                res.send({success: false, msg:'authentication error'})
                console.log(err);
            }
            else if (user.length != 0) {
                res.send({success: false, msg:'Email already exists'})
                console.log(err, 'email already exists'+email);
            }else {
                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);       
                }
            res.send({ success: true, msg: 'Your account created successfully! ' });
        });
            }
        })

    }
});
```

I got this error :

> ```
> events.js:160
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
> ```

Comment: Because you are "overwriting" the response object from the route here. `User.find({ email: req.body.email}, function(res,err, user)` Instead such calls should be `User.find({ email: req.body.email}, function(err, user)` where `err` **always** comes first. There is no need to "pass in variables" as what you seem to think you are doing. They are already in the "current scope".

Comment: thanks for your comment ! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you have a function argument whose name is shadowing that of the `res` in the parent scope. When you have variables with the same name in different scopes, the variable in the closest scope "wins." Rename one or the other so that the names are unique so that you can access the correct variable.